# How to solve relative path issue in include file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application structure that looks something like this :

```
/Views/Page1.html
/Views/SubFolder/Page2.html
```

Now each page will have a link in the head to a javascript, this will contain common includes like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/commonIncludes.js"></script>
```

So far so good, since we know the location of each starting html page and can directly adjust the relative path to the script directory.

The problem is that inside this commonIncludes.js file there is code which will actually write out the js includes like this :

```
// JQuery UI 
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery-ui-latest.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery-ui-layout-latest.min.js"></script>');
```

And here is where the problem comes in because the relative path is not calculated from commonIncludes.js instead it's from the calling .html page, and that can reside anywhere in the application structure.

referencing from root too won't work like this "\" because the site makes use of IIS applications so that the URL ends up looking something like this :

http://mysite/test

http://mysite/prod

http://mysite/testForCustomerX

So I'm looking for a way for the path to adjust or be set regardless of where the calling html is located using relative paths.

Comment: This  src="../ means you are getting out two folder before project directory Did you try to use "~/foldername", "~foldername". Just wanted to help. You can double check your file location comparing it to your code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the current URL with "window" object? then you can use window.location.host to know in witch environment you are.

instead of

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery-ui-latest.min.js"></script>');
```

use this

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://host/script/jquery-ui-latest.min.js"></script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

// Use this style.

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//script/jquery-ui-latest.min.js"></script>');
```